# ValueError - Python Django

Tags: python, django, valueerror

I went through forums and did some changes in my codes but the problem is still there. I did migrate and makemigrations, and even deleted migrate and recreate it again.

I also added default=0 to the models.py code:

> age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

I'll appreciate you if you help me on this issue.
These are some lines of codes, let me know if you need any other information.

**This is the error:**

```
ValueError at /basic_app/create/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/create/
Django Version: 2.1.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create'
Exception Location: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\myDjanEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 965
Python Executable:  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\myDjanEnv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\django_lecture\\djan_advance\\advcbv',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myDjanEnv\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myDjanEnv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myDjanEnv\\lib',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myDjanEnv',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myDjanEnv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**This is __init__.py file, line 960-965:**

> ```
> def get_prep_value(self, value):
>     from django.db.models.expressions import OuterRef
>     value = super().get_prep_value(value)
>     if value is None or isinstance(value, OuterRef):
>         return value
>     return int(value)
> ```

**The models.py file:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,related_name='students',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**urls.py file in basic_app folder:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.schoolListView.as_view(),name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.schoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
    url(r'^create/$',views.schoolCreateView.as_view(),name='create')
]
```

**views.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (View,TemplateView,
                                ListView,DetailView,
                                CreateView,UpdateView,
                                DeleteView)
from . import models

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class schoolListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'schools'
    model = models.School

class schoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'

class schoolCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('name','principal','location')
    model = models.School
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing the keyword create. You should share your views.py too.

Comment: Post edited. I added view.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is your regex capture for `pk` in the detail route in urls.py, specifically this line:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.schoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
```

I think you meant `[-\w]` as non alpha characters, but what this searches for is a hyphen (`-`) or any alpha, numeric, or underscore character (`\w`). Thus when you go to the route `/basic_app/create/`, `'create'` matches the pattern `[-\w]+` and is used as the primary key. Since `'create'` is composed of alpha characters and cannot be cast to an integer, you get the error `"invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create'"`.

To fix this, I think you'll want to only match numeric characters for the detail route. You could do something like:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.schoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
```